# I am new to Android Studio, and I am creating a wallpaper app, but I want the wallpapers to change automatically after a certain amount of time

Tags: android-studio

this my code it just shows a button and when you press it, it sets the image *world* as the device wallpaper, if you need more details just ask, I'm new so I don't know what you need to be able to help me :)

```
    package com.example.dailybible;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setWallpaper();
            }
        } );
    }

    private void setWallpaper () {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.world);
        WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at how easy to change an Image on the screen every 5 seconds:

XML file:

```xml
setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/yourImageViewID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="@string/inspect"/>
```

MainActivity.java file:

I added image1,image2,image3 to "drawable" folder.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView wallpaper;
public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.guardian,R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wallpaper = findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewID);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i=0;
        public void run() {
            wallpaper.setImageResource(mThumbIds[i]);
            i++;
            if(i>mThumbIds.length-1)
            {
                i=0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);  //for interval...
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); //for initial delay..
```

I see your code has a button. 
[Here is a simple example of how to change the image with a button.](https://mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/)